# Observations becoming NA when ordering levels of factors in R with ordered()

Tags: r, factors

Hi have a longitudinal data frame `p` that contains 4 variables and looks like this:

```
> head(p)
    date.1           County.x providers beds    price
1 Jan/2011              essex       258 5545 251593.4
2 Jan/2011 greater manchester       108 3259 152987.7
3 Jan/2011               kent       301 7191 231985.7
4 Jan/2011      tyne and wear       103 2649 143196.6
5 Jan/2011      west midlands       262 6819 149323.9
6 Jan/2012              essex         2   27 231398.5
```

The structure of my variables is the following:

```
'data.frame':   259 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ date.1   : Factor w/ 66 levels "Apr/2011","Apr/2012",..: 23 23 23 23 23 24 24 24 25 25 ...
 $ County.x : Factor w/ 73 levels "avon","bedfordshire",..: 22 24 32 65 67 22 32 67 22 32 ...
 $ providers: int  258 108 301 103 262 2 9 2 1 1 ...
 $ beds     : int  5545 3259 7191 2649 6819 27 185 24 70 13 ...
 $ price    : num  251593 152988 231986 143197 149324 ...
```

I want to order `date.1` chronologically. Prior to apply `ordered()`, this variable does not contain `NA` observations.

```
> summary(is.na(p$date.1))
   Mode   FALSE    NA's 
logical     259       0
```

However, once I apply my function for ordering the levels corresponding to `date.1`:

```
p$date.1 = with(p, ordered(date.1, levels = c("Jun/2010", "Jul/2010",
                               "Aug/2010", "Sep/2010", "Oct/2010", "Nov/2010", "Dec/2010", "Jan/2011", "Feb/2011",
                                                          "Mar/2011","Apr/2011", "May/2011", "Jun/2011", "Jul/2011", "Aug/2011", "Sep/2011",
                                                          "Oct/2011", "Nov/2011", "Dec/2011" ,"Jan/2012", "Feb/2012" ,"Mar/2012" ,"Apr/2012",
                                                          "May/2012", "Jun/2012", "Jul/2012", "Aug/2012", "Sep/2012", "Oct/2012", "Nov/2012",
                                                          "Dec/2012", "Jan/2013", "Feb/2013", "Mar/2013", "Apr/2013", "May/2013",
                                                          "Jun/2013", "Jul/2013", "Aug/2013", "Sep/2013", "Oct/2013", "Nov/2013", 
                                                          "Dec/2013", "Jan/2014",
                                                          "Feb/2014", "Mar/2014", "Apr/2014", "May/2014", "Jun/2014", "Jul/2014" ,"Aug/2014",
                                                          "Sep/2014", "Oct/2014", "Nov/2014", "Dec/2014", "Jan/2015", "Feb/2015", "Mar/2015",
                                                          "Apr/2015","May/2015", "Jun/2015" ,"Jul/2015" ,"Aug/2015", "Sep/2015", "Oct/2015",
                                                          "Nov/2015")))
```

It seems I miss some observations.

```
> summary(is.na(p$date.1))
   Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
logical     250       9       0
```

Has anyone come across with this problem when using `ordered()`? or alternatively, is there any other possible solution to group my observations chronologically?

Comment: You don't use the `order()` function anywhere in your code, as far as I can tell.

Comment: What is the output of `table(p$date.1)`?

Comment: @nicola, I have already edited the function. Effectively is `ordered ()`. @coffeinjunky, `p` is an unbalanced panel. Some levels may not be in certain months. However, I don´t understand why some become `NA`.

Comment: You might take a look at the `zoo` package and its `as.Date.yearmon` function.

Comment: Did you examine the nine records that now have missing date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that one of your `p$date.1` doesn't matched to any of the levels. Try this `ord.mon`as the levels.

```
ord.mon <- do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(month.abb, 2010:2015), sep = "/"))
```

Then, you can try this to see if there's any mismatch between the two.

```
p$date.1 %in% ord.mon
```

Last, You can also sort the data frame after transforming the `date.1` columng into `Date` (Note that you have to add an actual date beforehand)

```
p <- p[order(as.Date(paste0("01/", p$date.1), "%d/%b/%Y")), ]
```

Comment: This is a really nice solution and does what I want indeed. Yet, there are still  levels within date that are `NA`. Thanks!

Comment: can you provide the result of `dput(p$date.1)`?

Comment: Prior to order:  structure something like `(c(23L, 23L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 43L,...., 
55L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), .Label = c("Apr/2011", 
"Apr/2012", "Apr/2013", "Apr/2014", "Apr/2015", "Aug/2011", "Aug/2012", 
"Aug/2013", "Aug/2014", "Aug/2015", "Dec/2010", "Dec/2011", "Dec/2012", 
"Dec/2013", "Dec/2014", "Dec/2015", "Feb/2011", "Feb/2012", "Feb/2013", 
"Feb/2014", "Feb/2015", "Feb/2016", "Jan/2011",... ), class = "factor")`

Comment: EDIT: After creating `p` again and re-running the code indicated above, now it does not consider `NAs` anymore. It is solved @zyurnaidi, many many thanks.